Expected number of draws from urn (with 3 sets of color balls) to get 2x as many red balls as blue balls.
I am computing the expected value of this event: suppose we're sampling with replacement from an urn, where the likelihood of red balls is $p$, the likelihood of blue balls is $q$, and the likelihood of white balls is $1-p-q$. Let $X$ denote the expected number $n$ of samples from the urn so that there's at least 2x as many red balls are there are blue balls, with any number of white balls. For example if $X=200$, then it means we have to sample 200 balls to get at least 2x as many red balls as blue balls.

I can write the expectation that there's exactly 2x as many red balls as blue balls with the r.v. $X'$:
\begin{align*}
E[X'] &= \sum_{n=3k}^{\infty} n \cdot \frac{n!}{k!(2k)!(n-3k)!} p^{2k} q^{k} (1-p-q)^{n-3k}
\\&= \frac{p^{2k} q^k}{k! (2k)!} \sum_{n=3k}^{\infty} n^2\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-3k)!} (1-p-q)^{n-3k}
\\&= \frac{p^{2k} q^k}{k! (2k)!} \sum_{n=3k}^{\infty} n^2 (n-1)(n-2)...(n-3k+1)(1-p-q)^{n-3k}.
\end{align*}

However from line three, I can simplify this expression no further using the tools that I know of.

How does one generalize from the expression above to the expected number of draws $n$ so that there's at least 2x as many reds as blues?


In question 1, you're talking about the expectation that a certain event happens. I think you should talk about the probability of this event, otherwise it's not really clear.
Could you also explain what is $n$ ?

If $p < 2q$, there is a positive probability there is never a time when there are at least $2$ times as many red balls are there are blue balls, and so no expected time.  If $p=2q$ then I would guess that the expected time could be infinite.

@Kolakoski54 I edited the question so that $n$ is more clear. $n$ refers to the total number of balls drawn from the urn needed, so that we see 2x as many red balls as blue balls. Henry are you stating the question needs to be refined some what so that the value of $p$ vs $q$ is more restricted?

Isn't the condition satisfied right at the start when both quantities are $0$?
